# React Router v6 in external package

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have an application with react router inside. All application is wrapped by Router component.

```
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route path = "/home/" element = { <HomePage />} />
        <Route path = "/desk/" element = { <Desk /> ) />
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

In my Desk component I import from another package my external component Table, which has Link, useLocation etc.

I have to wrap everything with Router in the Table component. So now I have **main Router in application and another Router in my library component**. In this case click on Link changes url in browser address bar but it doesn't make main router to route components properly.

If I remove Router component in my library it shows errors such as "useHref() may be used only in the context of a Router component.".

Could you please help me to solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the webpack configuration. It has to be the only one react-router-dom component. I thought it was so, because I add 'externals' in my webpack config of the library with Table component.

But also I have to add this to my webpack config of main application.

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react-router-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-router-dom'),
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this example from react router docs:

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Try keeping only the top level `Router` wrapper and remove the one from inside the `Table`

Comment: This is the only option. Thanks!